# LevelDB and Node: get last key without iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, leveldb

I´m experimenting with LevelDB and Node.

I have a DB with 20 keys:value pairs. However, I want to add more programmatically and avoid getting the length (or last key index) using createReadStream() and iteration (i++) just for performance purposes. It works well now, but... 
What´s going to happen when I have 3000. I want to be able to get the last key on the db.

I could not find a function to do it in the documentation, and, outside iterating

I cannot find a way to do it.

Did anyone achieve this?

I will appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call SeekToLast. This will position iterator at the last element.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you know some command or workaround but for Level(JavaScript)? Again thanks